# GET Response = 200 but returning success: fail

Tags: android, json, get, google-oauth, httpurlconnection

So I have a bit of code that is returning me a GET response Code of 200 but will tell me that it is failing.

Here is the bit of code that is failing:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {

            // Do some validation here

            try {
                URL url = new URL(API_URL + authPreferences.getToken());
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("GET Response code:" + responseCode);
//                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("client_id", ClientId);
//                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("client_secret", ClientSecret);
//                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "JWT " + authPreferences);
                Log.i("URL", url.toString());
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString();

                } finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if (response == null) {
                response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.i("INFO", response);
            responseView.setText(response);
            //
            // TODO: check this.exception
            // TODO: do something with the feed

//            try {
//                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
//                String requestID = object.getString("requestId");
//                int likelihood = object.getInt("likelihood");
//                JSONArray photos = object.getJSONArray("photos");
//                .
//                .
//                .
//                .
//            } catch (JSONException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
        }
    }
```

I need the API_URL + authPreferences.getToken() to return me a token from the API_URL. The data type is JSON so maybe I am not handling that correctly? If you guys need to see any other big of my code just let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The request and invalidate

```
public void requestToken() {
        Account userAccount = null;
        String user = authPreferences.getUser();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        for (Account account : mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE)) {
            if (account.name.equals(user)) {
                userAccount = account;
                break;
            }
        }

        mAccountManager.getAuthToken(userAccount, "oauth2:" + SCOPE, null, this, new OnTokenAcquired(), null);
    }

    private void invalidateToken() {
        AccountManager mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        mAccountManager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", authPreferences.getToken());
        authPreferences.setToken(null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == AUTHORIZATION_CODE) {
                requestToken();
            } else if (requestCode == ACCOUNT_CODE) {
                String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                authPreferences.setUser(accountName);

                // invalidate old tokens which might be cached. we want a fresh
                // one, which is guaranteed to work
                invalidateToken();
                requestToken();
            }
        }
    }


    public class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
            try {
                Bundle bundle = result.getResult();
                Intent launch = (Intent) bundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                if (launch != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(launch, AUTHORIZATION_CODE);
                } else {
                    String token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                    authPreferences.setToken(token);
                    doCoolAuthenticatedStuff();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know its failing? Do you get *"THERE WAS AN ERROR"* in your `responseView` or something?

Comment: I get {"success": false, "error": "oauth failed"} in my responseView :(

Comment: This {"success": false, "error": "oauth failed"} you got in response body. May be due to your token access fail. I think you have to check token expire or used for any other device.

Comment: Hmm, my code is supposed to invalidate the old token and then request a token again. Maybe that isn't happening? I have updated my original with the invalidate/request.